# Translating an inequality word problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following problem:

> Camilo is a baker of cupcakes. John is also a baker of cupcakes. Camilo's number of cupcakes produced, c, will be no more than 20 cupcakes apart from John's production, j. What expression describes this scenario?

I thought this would require an inequality and an absolute value part. So I thought of something like this:

$$|j-c| \leq 20$$

However, when I put that on the number line,  it seems that the possible values are a range of 40. So a way to remedy this would be to do:

$$|j-c| \leq 10$$

However, I am not sure which one is correct.

Comment: The first one seems to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt was correct. The range should be $40$, because Camilo can bake anywhere from $20$ more to $20$ less than John's amount of cupcakes. Altogether, the inequality will end up being
$$j-20\le c\le j+20$$
or
$$|j-c|=20$$
with a range of $40$ cupcakes.

Yum!